# TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 3

Tags: python, python-3.9

Estoy elaborando una herramienta de python muy básica que crea directorios y archivos para poder crear un proyecto vacío de python y poder rellenarlo. A la hora de ejecutarla me da el error

> TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 3

Os paso todo el código:

```
import os
from shutil import rmtree
import shutil

#Funciones

def clear():
    if os.name == "nt":
        os.system("cls")
    else:
        os.system("clear")

def crearcarpetas():
    os.mkdir("sample")
    os.mkdir("docs")
    os.mkdir("tests")
    os.mkdir("C_DIR_AND_C_FILES")

def creararchivos():
    file = open("setup.py", "w")
    file2 = open("README.md", "w")
    file3 = open("LICENSE", "w")
    file4 = open("requirements.txt", "w")
    file5 = open("sample/__init__.py", "w")
    file6 = open("sample/helpers.py", "w")
    file7 = open("docs/conf.py", "w")
    file8 = open("docs/index.rst", "w")
    file9 = open("tests/test_basic.py", "w")
    file10 = open("tests/testadvanced.py", "w")

#Codigo 


clear()

op1 = input("1.-Crear repo 99.-Salir\n\n>>> ")

if op1 == "1":
    op1_1 = input("Indica el directorio\n\n>>> ")
    op1_2 = input("Quieres borrar los archivos de", op1_1, "...Y/N...")
    if op1_2 == "Y" or "y" or "yes":
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(op1_1)
        except OSError as e:
            print("Error")
        crearcarpetas()
        creararchivos()
    elif op1_2 == "N" or "n" or "no":
        print("Estamos creando los directorios y archivos necesarios, espere porfavor")
        crearcarpetas()
        creararchivos()
    else:
        SystemError
elif op1 == "99":
    SystemExit
else:
    print("Error")
    SystemError

print("El programa ha creado los archivos en:", os.getcwd(), "satisfactoriamente")
```

Comment: Claramente estas pasando más parámetros de los que deberías y esto es en el `input` donde defines la variable `op1_2 `. La función `input()` solo recibe un parámetro. Por otro lado Cierra los archivos luego de abrirlos!!!!!  No me imagino cuanta memoria consumirá tu programa :/

Comment: y como hago para que pueda almacenar el directorio en esa variable??

Comment: claramente la respuesta que te dieron es correcta y es la que te hubiera dado :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta cuando defines la variable `op1_2`, que estas pasando mas parámetros de los que permite. Prueba formateando el input tal que así

```py
op1_2 = input(f"Quieres borrar los archivos de {op1_1} ...Y/N...")
```

Answer (score 3):

El error se encuentra en esta linea:

op1_2 = input("Quieres borrar los archivos de", op1_1, "...Y/N...")

intenta concatenar los strings y la variable a ver que tal te va, saludos!

Comment: y la solución seria.....??